# How to package a target with dependencies using CMake?

Tags: cmake, packaging

I work on a big project: a lot of targets, half an hour build on a quad core i7 laptop.

My goal is to build one executable target which depends only on part of those other targets in the project, and package it for Linux and for Windows. I need the result to be a "relocatable" package. That is it won't be installed to any standard location but is required to run wherever the users will have unpacked it.

I can build the target in question and it runs fine from the build tree. So I know that all the pieces are there, I just need to package them.

It sounds like it should be possible using a combination of `install()` and `fixup_bundle()` but in practice details always get in the way. Here's what i tried so far.

#### Naive install-fixup

First thing I tried was

```
get_target_property(MYTARGET_LOCATION mytarget LOCATION)
get_filename_component(MYTARGET_NAME ${MYTARGET_LOCATION} NAME)
install(TARGET mytarget DESTINATION . COMPONENT mycomponent)
install(CODE "include(BundleUtilities)
    fixup_bundle(\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${MYTARGET_NAME} \"\" \"\")"
    COMPONENT mycomponent)
```

This didn't work because `install()` stripped `RPATH` from my executable and `fixup_bundle()` couldn't find any dependencies from my project.

#### Keep RPATH

Then I tried to keep RPATH hoping that the absolute build tree references would help `fixup_bundle()`:

```
get_target_property(MYTARGET_LOCATION mytarget LOCATION)
get_filename_component(MYTARGET_NAME ${MYTARGET_LOCATION} NAME)
install(PROGRAMS ${MYTARGET_LOCATION} DESTINATION . COMPONENT mycomponent)
install(CODE "include(BundleUtilities)
    fixup_bundle(\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${MYTARGET_NAME} \"\" \"\")"
    COMPONENT mycomponent)
```

This almost worked, `fixup_bundle()` found all the dependencies and copied them into `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. But then verification failed because `fixup_bundle()` didn't change `RPATH`, and `verify_app()` found references outside my bundle location.

#### Summary

I have a feeling that I work against CMake authors' intent and there should be another, better way of solving this. Also I have no idea how `fixup_bundle()` is supposed to work under Windows. So what is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's wondering---I ended up implementing my own installation script on top of GetPrerequisites.cmake.

As a general observation, CMake does not seem to consider separate packaging of individual components as a viable option. If you want that, you're on your own.